# Format as currency within a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I am trying to sum a column of dollar amounts and label it as "Total: $xx,xxx.xx" in the first row of that column.

I have gotten as far as 
="Cost - " & Text(SUM(B2:B), "$0.00")

BUT, it is not correctly formatting the dollar amount.  I.e. it reads "$10000.00" instead of "$10,000.00" (missing the comma)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use the [DOLLAR](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dollar.php) function.

> =DOLLAR(1345, 2)
>
> Result: "$1,345.00"

Comment: Brilliant - I figured there was a simple answer.  Thank you for your help... The site is telling me I have to wait a few more minutes to mark your answer as accepted...

Comment: No problem, I was originally going to just comment but it wouldn't format as nice.